# jQuery Facebook-like comment system

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, pdo

I've developed a jQuery comment system here: **http://jsfiddle.net/CKqWz/** with the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#commentlink1").click(function () {
        $("#commentbox1").toggle("slow");
    });
    $("#commentlink2").click(function () {
        $("#commentbox2").toggle("slow");
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#post_box").click(function() {
        $('#post_btn').show('slow');
    });

        $("#post_box").blur(function() {
        $('#post_btn').hide('slow');
    });
});
```

I was wondering how do I go about getting the messages and comments to "stick" once the user clicks the comment button.

By "stick" I mean update the page instantaneously with a new message or comment and allow the user to write another message or comment if they want to. Hopefully that makes sense - I am trying to develop something similar to the Facebook commenting system.

I need to use this as a basis for developing the AJAX which will send this information to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For realtime update of a page or a part of a page, you must be using ["Comet" technology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29), such as forever-iframe with script tag injection, long polling of a server, JSON polling of a server etc.

Also [HTML5 WebSockets](http://www.websocket.org/quantum.html) is a newer option.

Either way you must fall back to long polling or JSON polling too just in case.

For example, [Socket.io for Node.js](http://socket.io/) does this automatically.